# Unsupported Operand Types theme_image_style

Tags: 7, theming, media

I'm using the following code to generate a thumbnail and it's URI. The URI works on its own (though it 404's) but whenever I add `theme_image_style` function it gives a fatal error: "Unsupported operand types in /theme.inc on line 1088"

```
$image_fields_src = array_column($image_fields, 'uri' );

// thumbnail uri
$thumburi = image_style_path('thumbnail', $image_fields_src[0]);
// generate thumbnail
$thumbnail = theme_image_style('thumbnail', $thumburi );
```

Comment: what is your drupal version ? 7  or 8 ? where do you use the codes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [theme_image_style](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21image%21image.module/function/theme_image_style/7.x) page you tried wrong parameters,

as an example, your code should be something like the following snippet

```
$variables = array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $image_fields[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri'],
        'width' => $image_fields[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['width'],
        'height' => $image_fields[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['height']
);
$thumbnail_image = theme_image_style($variables);
```

and in short

```
$thumbnail_image = theme('image_style', array(
        'style_name' => 'thumbnail',
        'path' => $image_fields[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['uri'],
));
```

Comment: Thanks. Why do I need to add width/height parameters? Shouldn't width and height already by assigned since thumbnail is a default size?

Comment: Also, I don't want to print the image, just have it accessible by other functions.

Comment: @Sam height and width assigned by your image styles dimension, defaults for thumbnail   is 100x100, you can see them on `admin/config/media/image-styles` ,  ok instead I print it I'll put it on a variable and do what you want with it.

Comment: thanks. Is simply setting it as a variable going to create the thumbnail (on the server) ? Because I seem to be getting 404s from the path unless I actually print the image.

Comment: @Sam you're welcome, yes, finally you must  render it ( by `print`, `echo` ,etc) in your theme.

Comment: Is it possible to render the image without showing it? So the image is created but I display it through a seperate custom built string.

Comment: @Sam I meant markups